# Transmit recorded video as it was captured from webcam

Tags: webcam

Is it possible to handle the webcam output and substitute it with a record video (using Ubuntu)? For example, I would like to registered a video and then use it as it was the video recorded by the webcam during a video conference. Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify. Do you want to replace your webcam video with another video stream, or do you want to route your webcam video to 2 separate applications so you can record or stream it while it's in use by a teleconferencing application, for example?

Comment: I would replace the webcam video with another video stream, in particular with a recorded video.

Comment: So https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ubuntu+virtual+webcam+-virtualbox took me to https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback or `v4l2loopback` which may be available via `apt` and might be up your alley.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `v4l2loopback` which is available via `apt`

- `sudo apt install v4l2loopback-utils v4l2loopback-dkms`

You will need to set things up and the number of cameras etc...

- https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback
- `modprobe v4l2loopback`

You can then stream to it using `ffmpeg`

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877809/dummy-video-device-v4l2loopback-webrtc
- `ffmpeg -re -f lavfi -i "movie=sample.mkv" -f v4l2 /dev/video0`

Then you can use a video conferencing application and select the virtual camera:
[image]